# Why isn't phantomjs returning

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am experimenting with PhantomJs and tried to get something from a page, but it never returns anything

```
page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js", function () {
    page.open(url, function (status) {   
        var result_page = page.evaluate(function () {
            return  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;
        });

        return result_page;
        phantom.exit();
    });
});
```

i am running this with phantomjs.exe but it nevers exits runs for ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to print it to console. So you should change

```
return result_page;
```

to

```
console.log(result_page);
```

This will also solve the problem that PhantomJS never terminates, because `page.open` returns before calling `phantom.exit();`.

On an unrelated note, you should call `page.includeJs` inside of `page.open`, because otherwise you just load another page where jQuery is not loaded anymore.

Comment: Maybe jQuery is already present in the page? If the answer solved your problem, consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it. You can upvote answer when you have enough reputation.